# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d is not a function - tensorflow js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

i'm trying to do a prediction with tensorflow js, but when I try to predict have de following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d is not a function
> at tfjs@latest:17:162006
> at tfjs@latest:17:159769
> at e.t.scopedRun (tfjs@latest:17:159898)
> at e.t.tidy (tfjs@latest:17:159666)
> at n (tfjs@latest:17:161982)
> at tfjs@latest:17:162468
> at e.t.scopedRun (tfjs@latest:17:159898)
> at e.t.runKernelFunc (tfjs@latest:17:162190)
> at slice_ (slice.js:177:17)
> at slice (operation.js:45:22)

This is my javascript code:

```js
<script>
    
    async function inicializar() {
        alert("estoy en inicialize");
        document.getElementById('prediccion').addEventListener('click', () => predecir());

    };

    async function predecir() {
        
        alert("estoy en predecir"); //Mensaje para chequear que entre aca
        const modelo = await tf.loadLayersModel('trained-model/model.json');
        const canvas = document.getElementById('output');
        
        alert(canvas);// Mensaje para ver si lee canvas como elemento HTML

      
        let tensorImg = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas).resizeNearestNeighbor([150, 150]).toFloat().expandDims();
        alert("pasa esto"); //Mensaje para chequear que entre aca
        alert(tensorImg); //Mensaje para ver si lee el tensor de la imagen
        
        prediction = modelo.predict(tensorImg).data(); //Aca me da error!!!!! TypeError: d is not a function
        
        alert("pase hasta aca"); //Mensaje para chequear que entre aca, pero no llega

        var respuesta;
        
        if (prediction <= .5) {
          respuesta = "Gato";
        } else {
          respuesta = "Perro";
        }
        document.getElementById("prediccion").innerHTML = respuesta;

    };
 
    inicializar()
    
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help!